# how to set the date & time Permanently

Tags: command-line, date

I have set the date & time but once I logout, it sets time back to old time slot.

How can I set the time permanently? I have used the `tzselect` command & then export localtime.

Comment: which Linux OS do you have ?

Comment: do you actually want to set date & time or do you want to change the timezone? if the former, to what date and time does your machine set it back to?

Comment: Are you booting from a recovery or installation media, or from a hard / SSD drive?

Answer (score 7):

If **systemd based system**, here you are ↴

### Date and Time

```
$ timedatectl set-time 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
```

And if you want to change the date or time only:

```
$ timedatectl set-time HH:MM:SS       /*for time only*/

$ timedatectl set-time YYYY-MM-DD     /*for date only*/
```

To verify the change:

```
$ timedatectl
```

To print the system date and time:

```
$ date
```

### TimeZone

You can use `timedatectl` as shown below to list the available timezones

```
$ timedatectl list-timezones
```

To select one:

```
$ timedatectl set-timezone 'yourNewTimeZone'
```

**N.B.** And if you want to use `tzselect`, be aware that for the change to be permanent, you need to add your export-line - for instance `TZ='yourNewTimeZone'; export TZ` in `$HOME/.bash_profile` or `$HOME/.bashrc`. BTW, be aware that `tzselect` command does not actually change the timezone for you.

Comment: also disable ntp first before setting to prevent error `timedatectl set-ntp no`, set the time, then set the hardware clock `hwclock -w`, then turn on back the ntp `timedatectl set-ntp yes`, assuming you already have correct timezone